# Matrix multiplication using pairs

Tags: c++, data-structures, matrix-multiplication

I am looking into alternate ways to do a Matrix Multiplication. Instead of storing my matrix as a two-dimensional array, I am using a vector such as

```
vector<pair<pair<int,int >,int > >
```

to store my matrix. The pair within my pair (pair) stores my indices (i,j) and the other int stores the value for the given (i,j) pair. I thought I might have some luck implementing my sparse array this way.

The problem is when I try to multiply this matrix with itself.

If this was a 2-d array implementation, I would have multiplied the matrix as follows:

```
   for(i=0; i<row1; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<col1; j++)
        {
          C[i][j] = 0;
         for(k=0; k<col2; k++) 
           C[i][j] += A[i][j] * A[j][k];
      }
    }
```

Can somebody point out a way to achieve the same result using my vector of 'pair of pairs'?

Thanks

Comment: One way is to use the same algorithm but with the indexing operations on the sparse matrix. This is inefficient though, unless you manage to get fast indexing operations (hashtables spring to mind). But I'm sure there are better algorithms out there (Google wasn't helpful :( )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you can store one value at one location. If you want to store several nonzero entries in the matrix, you will need more pairs of pairs in a larger structure.

`map<pair<int, int>, int>` would be the next logical step. Now you can iterate over rows because the `first` coordinate is more significant in the `map`'s sorting order.

To iterate over columns, reverse that precedence:

```
typedef pair<int, int> mx_coord;
struct reverse_compare {
    bool operator() (mx_coord const &l, mx_coord const &r) const
        { return l.second < r.second? true :
                 r.second < l.second? false : l.first < r.first; }
};

typedef map< mx_coord, int > matrix;
typedef map< mx_coord, int, reverse_compare > matrix_transpose;
```

To multiply A by B, transpose B and iterate over A and B, multiplying any elements whose less-significant coordinates match, as the ordering naturally lets you go line-by-line and column-by-column.

To transpose B:

```
matrix_transpose b_t( b.begin(), b.end() ); // complexity: n log n
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe a transforming iterator is a better way to go. Well, this should work well enough to prove the concept.

Comment: Thanks Potatocorn - Your suggestion is to use a Map of 'pairs' instead a vector. What is it that we gain by using the Map in this context? I am also having some trouble understanding the reverse_compare. Can you please shed some light on that? Thanks

Comment: @sc_ray: The `map` allows you to have more than one nonzero element. Given a pair of coordinates, you look up the value. `reverse_compare` is used to transpose the matrix, allowing you to iterate over columns first, which is important to multiplication.

Comment: Thanks Potatocorn. That makes sense.